# My Visual C++ program crashes when running std::sort

Tags: arrays, sorting, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to create an array of random numbers, and then sort it in ascending order. But when I input 3 or higher to add numbers to the array it crashes after the array has been filled and output to the window, and it tries to begin sorting it. I can't seem to figure out why this happens...

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>

using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    int size, i;
    int *array;
    array = new int[size];
    srand(time(NULL));

    Console::WriteLine("Input amount of numbers you'd like in the array: ");
    String^ str = Console::ReadLine();
    size = System::Convert::ToInt32(str);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        array[i] = rand();
    }
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        Console::Write(array[i] + ", ");
    }

    Console::WriteLine("\n\n");

    std::sort(array, array + size);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        Console::Write(array[i] + ", ");
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to allocate your array AFTER the user enters the input size.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you very much :)